# in celery rabbitmq exchange type topic is not working properly

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I have two python projects. Both are enabled with celery. What i am trying to do here is from project A i am sending task using send_task() method. The task which is i am sending is in project B. So the project B's worker is up and its showing the task. Till this condition everything is working fine. But when i make project A's worker up its starting to provide key error here. What exactly happens here is that
1) In first attempt of send_task() project B's worker is receiving the task. And everything is working as expected.
2) In second attempt of send_task() it fails. Because project A's worker is trying to receive the task which is not present in project A so its throwing key error.
3) In third attempt of send_task() project B's worker is receiving the task. And everything is working as expected.
4) In fourth attempt of send_task() it fails. Because project A's worker is trying to receive the task which is not present in project A so its throwing key error.
This process keeps repeating again and again.

Project A Queue:-

```
                .> mplogin.sync     exchange=mplogin(topic) key=mplogin.sync


[tasks]


[2016-06-03 11:11:04,427: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
[2016-06-03 11:11:04,468: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-06-03 11:11:05,476: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-06-03 11:11:05,984: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@gaurav-All-Series ready.
```

Project B Queue:-

```
                .> mplogin.sync     exchange=mplogin(topic) key=mplogin.sync


[tasks]
  . mplogin.sync.register

[2016-06-03 11:12:57,941: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
[2016-06-03 11:12:57,949: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-06-03 11:12:58,955: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-06-03 11:12:58,980: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py:75: UserWarning: A node named celery@gaurav-All-Series is already using this process mailbox!

Maybe you forgot to shutdown the other node or did not do so properly?
Or if you meant to start multiple nodes on the same host please make sure
you give each node a unique node name!

  warnings.warn(W_PIDBOX_IN_USE.format(node=self))
[2016-06-03 11:12:58,983: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@gaurav-All-Series ready.
```

I am making both workers up using

```
celery -A tasks worker -l info
```

Task in Project B:-

```
@sync_app.task(name='mplogin.sync.register')
def register(user_obj):
    return "Its working!!!!"
```

Sending task from project A:

```
    from tasks import login_async_app

    abc = login_async_app.send_task('mplogin.sync.register',kwargs={'user_obj': 500})
```

sync_app is celery application in project B & login_async_app is celery application in project A.

I think this issue i am facing is because of exchange_type="topic"
I tried using direct but its not working.
please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Both workers are consuming tasks from same queue.

When you have started worker A, it hasn't recognised any tasks (as seen from log).

```
[tasks]
```

Worker B has recognised only 1 task.

```
[tasks]
  . mplogin.sync.register
```

You have to make sure both workers recognise both tasks. You can do that by properly configuring celery.

You can also use `CELERY_IMPORTS` to mention the list of modules that celery imports.

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('foo.bar.app1.task1', 'foo.bar.app2.task2')
```

By properly importing tasks, you can avoid that error.